# com.opencsv not found when lauched from console

Tags: java, maven, console, opencsv, csvreader

I have a Maven project that simply reads a CSV file and writes data to another file. When building/running from IntelliJ, it works fine but when I run `$ java read.java` from the console, it gives

```
src/main/java/read.java:1: error: package com.opencsv does not exist
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
```

Same thing for `CSVWriter`.
I added the .jar to my project but it was not successful. How can I launch my app from console (so I can use arguments as I launch it)?

Thank you

Comment: You can put arguments in IntelliJ as well, just edit the run configuration and you should find the ability to add arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the neccesary jars to the classpath.

For example:

```
java -cp libs/opencsv-5.2.jar read.java
```

See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html